# Typescript - constructor argument types depending on class property type

Tags: typescript, class, types, constructor

I have a class inheritance pattern where I would like the type of an argument's constructor depends on the type of a class' property.
Here is my pattern :

```
class Animal{
    metadata : any
    constructor( metadata){
        this.metadata = metadata
    }

    setMetadata(metadata : this['metadata']){
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

}


class Dog extends Animal{
    metadata : {
        name : string,
        owner : string
    }

    constructor(metadata){
        super(metadata)
    }
}

class Lion extends Animal{
    metadata : {
        free : boolean,
        country : string
    }

    constructor(metadata){
        super(metadata)
    }
}
```

Imagine we create a Lion

```
const lion = new Lion({});
```

the signature of `lion.setMetadata` is the one I expect :

```
(metadata: {
    free: boolean;
    country: string;
})=> void
```

and the following code is a typescript error :

```
lion.setMetadata({inconsistentKey : 'refused By typescript'})
```

Now I would like to achieve the same behaviour directly with the constructor.
The following code should be accepted :

```
const lion = new Lion({free : true, country : 'somewhere'})
```

But not this one :

```
const lion = new Lion({})
```

This suppose the constructor of Lion to infer the type of its arguments from the type of Lion instance metadata.
More precisely, I would expect `lion.constructor` to have signature :

```
(metadata: {
    free: boolean;
    country: string;
})=> Lion
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in typescript ?
Because the this keyword in type is not available for static member of class, thus not available for the constructor.

Comment: You can define metadata type as a generic parameter https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmEAeAKgPmgbwChpjpkBTAFzABMwqAuaTIk4Ae3ggoCcBXYCm24AKclVoMmASnwsSJCgAtEEAHRiadMNAC8pSpqpzoAXwLGIlALIGJYUba2NMMwvPlKV6x1V37xWgDcxmZmBKCQMAAibADm0GQAHhRk8NQwCCho6G4k8GDkjFzciPCxADTGbADu8GTcRTylsQQmuIRhEVDQADKIHAnJqelwSKgYucQAZtxkZIwARmxsIGRg8JXy7LzwPACejSVlre2t5uEcXNAg-fB+ddW9t8J4M3PQjDy8ZOXQ27vcPYfaAAcggbHI1UU9TIIJMUnMNw4qksFBsASoL1K7E4KhSuwA0mQgYwQbMprxLNRoAAhIEUPYABzIEGAJUZFDhCJxVyR8AATPcyI8+hwXvCgA

Comment: What are you expecting to gain by adding `setMetadata` method if `metadata` is a public field? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmEAeAKgPmgbwChpjpgB7eCAFwCcBXYKsmgCgAc6AjERYaZAKZUwAEzDCAXNEwBKfAF8CigqEgwAImQDm0AQA8qA+CJgIUadIRLR4YQVOo1E8LQBoiJMgHd4Amg9pnLSVcQmVVKGgAGUQKXQMjEzgkVAwrEgAzGgEBKU4yMhABMHh3a3I6eFoATwCnFxD8JQIW8koqaB44gF4bAS9o2PgWPCyc6ClaOgFXUjJKmonoAHIIMkEvAAs-AWX5GRau+AA6QWExYWhe0eyBJYy0CBm5hZpqpdX1-u3svYIj05CUTiMBXfDONoQRDUIxUADSAneUmW2QydCeImgACF3lRqmwBBBgE42FQ-ioKNROkMAExg3wDGIUEb7IA

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes, thanks you, this can be the solution. However, I would hope an equivalent of `this` for the constructor ; I find the syntax with Animal<{key:value}> not very readable and easy to use while the code growth

@Lesiak this is just for the example.

Comment: Then you can pass the whole class as generic parameter https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmEAeAKtApgDwBcd4ATGAb2mRwLBLFoC5ox4BPaAXwD5pyAoaEKo06DMM0wBtAOTVa9WjIC6g4cAD28CAQBOAV2AENugBTyxTaNLmjFYFQEo+a4cIIALRBAB0F+9AAvCIK4q5c-OEQNACyduLm8VY2-uJOLm5unt5+SWBBIZZgANzhnPzl-KCQMAAyiFq4hMRkcEioGPVavAJuqbQAhMy9mUIAZro4ONDMAEYaGiA4rAA04W6a+vB6HMw6uojwAOZlFZFVWjrQIA3wBfA4AO7QXfCm5BNTM9B6+jgr0E2210u2gMggGmojw8OEmMk4jkiNy0PmiBDioVo70Omm03iI2wA0jhQTJJmN9NESNAAEIcAhsAAOOAgwAOjII8MRuKuyPgACZ7k8Xrd3gigA

Comment: @AlekseyL. you might want `declare metadata` instead of `metadata!` due to how class fields will end up being implemented in JS (subclass fields will overwrite base class fields)

Comment: @Aristote "disponible" is not an English word; do you mean "available"?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Indeed, this can do the trick, thanks !

Comment: @jcalz exact, but I don't know how to edit it

Comment: You can [edit] your question by clicking that link or the "Edit" link under your question.  (But I've made the change myself.)